# Por que o primeiro elemento do vetor sai como zero sem ter guardado esse valor lá?

Tags: c, array, for

Por qual razão o código a seguir imprime um 0 no começo do *output*?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
// Escreva  um  programa    que leia    do  teclado 8   valores,    e   em  seguida os  
// imprima  em  ordem   inversa.


void main()
{
    int numero[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int i = 0;

    printf("\nA distribuicao desses numeros em ordem inversa : ");

    for(i=8;i>=0;i--){
        printf("\n--------\n%d",numero[i]);
    }

}
```

Saida:

```
A distribuição desses números em ordem inversa:
--------
0
--------
8
--------
7
--------
6
--------
5
--------
4
--------
3
--------
2
--------
1
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.1034 seconds with return value 11
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faz uma análise o que o código executa. Quando você programa você tem que entender o que o computador fará, entender todo o código.

Na verdade neste caso nem precisa muito, só olhar o resultado. Conte quantos números foram impressos. Nove, certo? Mas o *array* só tem 8 elementos, então um dos números ele pegou lixo na memória e imprimiu. C é assim, ele faz o que você manda, é problema seu garantir que tem a coisa certa na memória.

No caso você está mandando imprimir o elemento número 8 em primeiro, mas só vai até o 7. Eu sei que deve estar achando estranho, mas pensa bem. Sem tem 8 elementos e um deles é o 0, conforme você mesmo fez, o último é o 7 e não 8. A mesma coisa quando colocamos todos os algarismos individualmente, colocamos de 0 a 9, totalizando 10 números diferentes.

Então se começasse do 7 tudo daria certo. De forma correta, mais organizada, legível e sem o que é desnecessário:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numero[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    printf("\nA distribuicao desses numeros em ordem inversa : ");
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) printf("\n--------\n%d", numero[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XGf0e0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pkpwyutk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Index.c).

Answer (score 1):

Em C os vetores começam do 0 e terminam em n-1 então seu loop deveria ser   `for(i=8;i>0;i--)` ou  `for(i=7;i>=0;i--)`. No seu código você está lendo uma memória fora pois está printando 9 elementos num vetor de 8 elementos.

Answer (score -1):

Essa linha esta com um índice a mais. Ou seja 9 elementos.

```
for(i=8;i>=0;i--){
    printf("\n--------\n%d",numero[i]);
}
```

O correto seria.

```
for(i=8;i>0;i--){
    printf("\n--------\n%d",numero[i]);
}
```